# Can Clang generate an import library when using the visibility attribute (without __declspec(dllexport))?

Tags: c++, windows, dll, clang

When using the Microsoft compiler, to export a class or function from a library you would use code similar to:

`class __declspec(dllexport) Foo {};`

With Clang (and GCC) you can use the visibility attribute to ensure that a symbol is visible:

`class __attribute__((visibility(default))) Foo {};`

Or rely on the visibility set at compile time.

When I compile with Clang on Windows, if a class is visible (even with explicit attribute), the function isn't exported (no import library is created).

Is it possible to get Clang to generate an import library without using the Microsoft extension `__declspec(dllexport)` which Clang *mostly* but not entirely supports.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "__declspec(dllexport) which Clang mostly but not entirely supports", which aspect of it doesn't it support?

Comment: @mstorsjo there are several bugs logged against `__declspec(dllexport)` for the LLVM project; here's one example that I've filed recently - https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=44016

Comment: Fair enough, that case does seem to deviate from MSVC behaviour.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it was the LLVM port that inspired Microsoft to fork their own.  They worked on it for a while, afaict it was exception handling was the harder nut to crack.  It got stable around VS2017 and is included in the VS installer.

Comment: @HansPassant what did Microsoft fork?

Comment: The code generator, ensuring binary compatibility.  The kind of thing you *have* to do to have any shot at creating usable DLLs.  The value-add of Clang is the front-end, not the back-end.

Comment: @HansPassant, I'd argue both are worthwhile using on Windows. Internal benchmarks are showing *significant* performance increase when using Clang/LLVM vs MSVC C1/C2. I believe MS helped the LLVM project implement PDB support, so would be great if they could help them out on other areas of compatibility.

Comment: @mstorsjo, here's another bug that I filed due to a difference between LLVM & MSVC - https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=41895

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To clarify a few things; it's not the compiler (Clang) itself that produces import libraries, but the linker, and the object file format plays a large role in the process.

Adjusting which symbols are exported via `__attribute__((visibility(default)))` (when either marking other symbols as hidden with `__attribute__((visibility(hidden)))`, or setting the default with something like `-fvisibility=hidden`, works with both GCC and Clang when building ELF object files. COFF doesn't have a similar per-symbol visibility flag.

When linking a DLL with MS link.exe, or LLVM's lld-link (which mimics link.exe's behaviour), only symbols either marked with `__declspec(dllexport)`, or listed in a def file that is passed to the linker, are exported.

Within the MinGW ecosystem (which brings a bit more of unix-like behaviours), the default is to export all global symbols (with some amount of logic to avoid exporting things that belong to the mingw base libraries themselves) if no symbols are explicitly chosen to be exported.

If linking with lld-link instead of MS link.exe (either by calling lld-link instead of link, if calling the linker directly, or by adding `-fuse-ld=lld` if invoking the linker via the clang-cl frontend), you can opt in to this behaviour by adding the lld specific option `-lldmingw`, which enables a number of MinGW-specific behaviours in lld.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping that Clang had the ability to automatically mark symbols as exported, if they were visible (based on the attribute, or the default), which would then allow the linker to generate an import library.

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to @mstorsjo 's answer, Here's an example of passing a def file to clang.

```
clang -shared structs.c -o structs.dll -Wl"/DEF:structs.def"
```

I struggled with this for a day, hope it helps someone ([explaination](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62360059/7186086))

Comment: Sometimes needs comma to work: -Wl,/def:structs.def