# Specifying the DEF file when compiling a DLL with Clang

Tags: c++, c, dll, clang, llvm

I am trying to compile a DLL using clang in windows

```
clang -shared structs.c -o structs.dll
```

but the symbols aren't being exported..

If I add __declspec(dllexport) to my declarations in structs.h, They symbols are exported to DLL.

But instead, I would like to do this using a DEF file (structs.def) I created, But I can't find how I pass the DEF file to clang.

Any help is appeciated :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured it out -

1. We can use the -Wl flag in clang to pass some comma-separated arguments to the linker.
2. DEF files can be specified using /DEF argument

Example

```
clang -shared structs.c -o structs.dll -Wl"/DEF:structs.def"
```

Comment: For those ones who was not able to make it working, you may try to use it with comma -Wl,/def:structs.def